# USB controller should get driver from Windows update, but has a driver error. What to do?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, usb-3

My brand new X299 PC (Cascade Lake X, Windows 10, untouched clean install) has a VIA USB host controller, hardware ID `PCI\VEN_1106&DEV_3483&SUBSYS_34831106&REV_01` with an error 43.

There isn't a driver provided for this, on any website, because it's apparently supposed to come from Windows Updates. But after Windows Updates finishes everything, this device isn't able to start.

I've tried a load of things - clean install Windows 10, uninstall/rescan devices, force  install other plausible drivers, turn off USB selective suspend and Windows fast startup - but none seem to work.

What can I do, to fix it?

Comment: Make and model of add in card?

Comment: @Moab - None, this is the bare motherboard.

Comment: Brand of PC?...

Comment: @Moab - Self built. Its still being put through basic testing so right now.its literally, motherboard (ASUS WS X299 SAGE), CPU+cooler (i9-10980xe and custom.water loop), PSU (EVGA Supernova 1000 P2), RAM (Corsair vengeance 4 x 32GB 3600), Intel.and Samsumg SSDs, and a Radeon RX550 video card. All new. No other cards, no software yet except.drivers (Windows Update and ASUS: the relevant driver is presumably from WU or the Win10 installer files), and installed with an official win10 2004 installer from Microsoft.

Comment: I would contact Asus support about the issue.